# Is it possible to update the order item quantity in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to update the ordered product quantity from the sales order view page (admin side). I have added a new button and actions for update order quantity. But I don't know what are the tables needs to updated for this. or else is there any other solution?(without creating new order concept).

I already gone through below one.

[Is it possible to update order items quantity in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563078/is-it-possible-to-update-order-items-quantity-in-magento)

Thanks

Comment: if u update order details once it is ordered, then what about the payment? Will the customer pays u again???

Comment: @PavanKumar  No.. the payment not a problem?. because we don't use any payments

Answer (score 0):

Orders data are saved in database tables sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_item.

You can find orders and order items data in your (tables prefix)_sales_flat_order and (tables prefix)_sales_flat_order_item respectively. but remember that when an order is placed Magento simply copies the data from its respective quote. so in my opinion you should be checking (table prefix)_sales_flat_quote and (table prefix)_sales_flat_quote_item first.